# Like button is working but not changing to Unlike in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, querying

I've been trying to debug this issue for a day together with my expert coder but we were unable to identify the issue here. The like button works perfectly all right and I am able to query the total likes, but the Clap button does not change to unlike and we are unsure why. I believe the error lies in either the html line:

```
{% if liked and post.slug == blog_post.slug %} Unlike {% else %} Like {% endif %}
```

or the django line:

```
context["liked"] = True if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists() else False
```

Big thanks if you can identify the issue here!

**views.py**

```
def home_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts 
    if request.method=="POST":
        slug=request.POST["submit_slug"]
        blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        context["liked"] = True if blog_post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists() else False
        context['total_likes'] = blog_post.total_likes()
    type_of_post = TypeofPostFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.all())
    context['type_of_post'] = type_of_post

    paginated_type_of_post = Paginator(type_of_post.qs, 13 )
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_page_obj = paginated_type_of_post.get_page(page)

    context['post_page_obj'] = post_page_obj

    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)


def LikeView(request, slug):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('must_authenticate')
    post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', ''))
```

```
<td class="table-primary">
   <form action="{% url 'HomeFeed:like_post' post.slug %}" method="POST"> 
       {% csrf_token %} 
              
       <button type="submit" name="submit_slug" value="{{ post.slug }}" class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>

       {% if liked and post.slug == blog_post.slug %} Unlike {% else %} Like 
       {% endif %}

       </button> 
       {{ post.total_likes }} Clap {{ post.total_likes|pluralize }}
         
   </form>
</td>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<slug>/like/', LikeView, name='like_post'),
```

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    chief_title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='blog_posts', blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

Comment: can you show your `models.py` entirely?

Comment: @SLDem Hi bro i have updated models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's a much simpler way to perform a check if a model exist in a `m2m` field in another model:

**html**

```
{% if request.user in blog_post.likes.all %} Unlike {% else %} Like {% endif %}
```

**view**

```
if request.user in blog_post.likes.all():
```

***P.S.** In your model you should rename the field `likes` to `likers` since its a relation with a `User` model not a `Like` model :)*

**EDIT**

So, to easily display a list of posts and their like buttons accordingly on a single page you wanna do this in your template:

**views.py**

```
def posts(request): 
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'blog_posts': blog_posts})
```

**index.html**

```
{% for post in blog_posts %}

    <h1>{{ post.chief_title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.author }} says: </p>
    <b>{{ post.body }}</b>
    <p> This post is liked by: </p>
    {% for user in post.likes %}
        <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    
    {% if request.user not in post.likes.all %} 
        <a href="{% url 'like_post' post.slug %}">Like</a>
    {% else %} 
        <a href="{% url 'like_post' post.slug %}">Unlike</a>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: hi bro, which part of the view should I add this to? `if request.user in blog_post.likes.all():
`

Comment: as im still starting to learn django i think itll be quite difficult to change and modify my whole view from likes to likers haha

Comment: well for starters you shouldn't do it in a view at all, since you have multiple objects on a same page it will be much easier to display those objects in a `queryset`(django object list) and use `jinja2s` `for` loop syntax to iterate over them and display the like buttons with the link, I'll show an example in an edit

Comment: sure 1 sec, I'll add that too

Comment: thank you bro!! I will note and try to implement your advise in another context. Just confirming that you havent added the reply for this right? : :hi bro, which part of the view should I add this to? if request.user in blog_post.likes.all():

Comment: `context['liked'] = request.user in blog_post.likes.all()` is where it WOULD go, but try to use my implementation instead :)

Comment: actually your codes for views.py and html did not work, CLAP was still shown. Any idea why it does not work? I'm referring to {% if request.user in blog_post.likes.all %} Unlike {% else %} Like {% endif %}

Comment: I cant use your implementations in this case as i have django filters inside and also args and kwargs,

Comment: basically the whole button works, just that the word in the button does not change from like to unlike.

Comment: but i am able to like and unlike.

Comment: it should be `{% if request.user not in post.likes.all %} 
        <a href="{% url 'like_post' post.slug %}">Like</a>
    {% else %} 
        <a href="{% url 'like_post' post.slug %}">Unlike</a>
    {% endif %}`

check my latest edit again :)

Comment: Bro I'm referring to the first code, not the second one

Comment: the one that you add if request.user in blog_post.likes.all():
 into the view

Comment: basically the like and unlike functionality is there, but just not sure why the words like dont change to unlike

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226815/discussion-between-sldem-and-timago).